# SharpSVN: Interface to Repo Browser

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

I need to open Repo Browser when the user clicks a button and after the user makes a selection using the Repo Browser, it should return the path selected, similar to open file dialog boxes etc.

Answer (score 0):

SharpSvn provides the Subversion API as a library, but it doesn't provide a default repository browser GUI. You could build one using SharpSvn (most likely using `SvnClient.List()`), but if you just want to use one I would recommend just invoking the TortoiseSVN UI via TortoiseProc.exe.

In the TortoiseSVN manual you can find how to invoke it on a specific target.

Comment: Yes I can use TortoiseProc.exe to invoke a URI but after the user selects a particular Directory, how can I get that location ? Like a Open file dialog box ?